# Unpublished APP in Google Play Store, no visible anymore, still customers can write reviews

Tags: comments, publish, delete-row, review, removeall

If I unpublished an APP in Google Play Store, no visible anymore, why still customers can write reviews and I get messages from Google with these reviews ?

The APP is installed in the phone of many users, and they can use the APP, but I dont understand how they can write reviews when they are not visible in Google Play Store.

How can I change this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.